# Missed snapshot tab in virtualbox

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and VirtualBox 4.1.12. All manuals and help documents refer to Snapshot tab in top right corner of Virtualbox manager. But I have no idea where can I find it. Screenshot is attached.
Does anybody know anyting about how can I get acces to Snapshot manager tab? (Take a snapshot I can when machine is running).

[image: Virtualbox manager screenshot]

Comment: I would ask that this question be considered for reopening.  I think it can and has helped a broader range of people and I see other people having the same people.

Comment: The question (and answer) did help me. I was getting mad with this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Suddenly found by random click: right click on bottom panel, and select there "Show toolbar" fix this.

[image]

Comment: I was just struggling with a screenshot for you. Glad you found it :)

Comment: can you tell me the location of the show toolbar option? Screen shots will be helpful

Comment: I've added image to my answer.